# How to put a value of single column into Multiple column in a right order (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas

In my df, I've already divided my single column(Instance_Parameter) to two new column(Instance and Parameter). The two col were made based on the "." available in the first col.

[image]

However, some time my Instance_parameter column doesn't have "." (See image 2) it means I only have parameter name available. When I try to divide this value (values without "."). I see it will appear in Instance column but not in parameter col. And I agree with it. 
[image]

However, my query is, How can I make sure values without "." in col "Instance_Parameter" will endup in only col "Parameter" but not in col "Instance"?

Initially, I try to check (Pic 3)if a new column(Parameter_1) show me True if my Col "Instance_Parameter" not include "." and false if include ".". However, I see this is also not showing me correct results?

Here is my code:

```
for x in Limit_File_1.Instance_Parameter:
    Limit_File_1[['Instance','Parameter']]=Limit_File_1.Instance_Parameter.str.split(".",expand=True)
    #print(Limit_File_1[1:5])
    if '.' not in Limit_File_1.Instance_Parameter:
        Limit_File_1['Parameter_1'] = 'True'
    else:
        Limit_File_1['Parameter_1'] = 'False'

Limit_File_1[10:115]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting. It would be nice to copy&paste your code into my IDE - especially if you also provided a demo-DF-creation script. With images I have to recreate all your work ... wich takes cosiderable time and effort on my end. Please post `code` as text - not images. You can format it by prepending / appending ``` to it

Comment: I just added my code. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is change order if None value in last column:

```
Limit_File_1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Instance_Parameter':['aaa.ff','ss','dd.gh'],

})

Limit_File_1[['Instance','Parameter']]= (Limit_File_1.Instance_Parameter
                                                     .str.split(".",expand=True))
m = Limit_File_1['Parameter'].isna()
(Limit_File_1.loc[m, ['Parameter','Instance']] = 
 Limit_File_1.loc[m, ['Instance','Parameter']].values)
print (Limit_File_1)
  Instance_Parameter Instance Parameter
0             aaa.ff      aaa        ff
1                 ss     None        ss
2              dd.gh       dd        gh
```

Another idea is split only rows with `.` and then replace missing values:

```
mask = Limit_File_1.Instance_Parameter.str.contains(".", regex=False)
Limit_File_1[['Instance','Parameter']] = (Limit_File_1.loc[mask, 'Instance_Parameter']
                                                      .str.split(".",expand=True))
Limit_File_1['Parameter']=Limit_File_1['Parameter'].fillna(Limit_File_1['Instance_Parameter'])
print (Limit_File_1)
  Instance_Parameter Instance Parameter
0             aaa.ff      aaa        ff
1                 ss      NaN        ss
2              dd.gh       dd        gh
```